# I want to display records in my textbox

Tags: vb.net

When i input the id number of the student in my TextBox, i want the details of that particular students to be displayed in my textbox, without using datagrid. i am using vb.net.

That is my code and i don't understand what's wrong:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from tblsupplier where pro_code = '" & txcode.Text & "'"
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    txname.Text = dr.item("sup_product")
    txprice.Text = dr.Item("sup_price")
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have left your application open to sql injection by adding the value of the textbox inline. Look up this topic please:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

As for your code, you need to call dr.Read() before you can actually access any properties from your query.

```
while (dr.Read()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: should i include the dr.item? it has an error sir. .
While (dr.Read())
            txname.Text = dr.Item("sup_product")
            txprice.Text = dr.Item("sup_price")
        End While

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could provide additional details about the error, friend. Like what SQL you are using, what was the error message, and which event triggers this reader command.

As it stands, it seems you haven't really sent the DataReader to scan the database. You need the `While reader.read()` loop.

Here is an example, using OLEDB in a function that fetches the data

Note that connstring is my SQL connection string to an Access Database

```
Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=MyDatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=;")

Function Mycheckifexistss(ByVal sqlCMDstring As String)
        Dim sqlCmd As New OLEDBCommand(sqlCMDstring, conn)
        Dim reader As OLEDBDataReader
        Dim result As String = ""
        Try
            conn.Open()
            reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
            While reader.Read
                result = reader(0) 'this returns the first field of the queried result.
            End While

            conn.Close()

             Return result
        Catch ex As Exception
            conn.Close() 'the first thing you want to do in an error, is to close the connection first.
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)


        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from tblsupplier where pro_code = '" & txcode.Text & "'"
       
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        
txname.Text = dr.Item("sup_product") 'this is wer the error occur says "Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()"

        txprice.Text = dr.Item("sup_price")

Comment: If you think this answer has solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the correct answer. 'tis proper netiquette.